# Eval not properly assigned when calling repl.start

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Using the following code:

```js
const repl = require('repl')

function simpleEval(cmd, context, filename, callback) {
    console.log('got eval')
}

function handleOutput(output) {
    console.log('got output ' + output)
    return ''
}

const server = repl.start({
    eval: simpleEval,
    prompt: 'Enter Userid: >> ',
    terminal: true,
    ignoreUndefined: true,
    writer: handleOutput
})
```

When I pause in the debugger after the server is created, it shows:

[image: eval not assigned, writer is]

Why isn't server.eval being set to the simpleEval function?

Comment: Why does it matter? Is your `simpleEval` function getting called or not?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3a3672ba6c8cb9143ee421d20e7c110e1284315b/lib/repl.js#L641

Comment: It is not being called. I get errors from trying to run what I type as javascript.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I was using a workspace in Visual Code and it was running the wrong executable. Make an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.